# Send IOT Data from Azure IOT Hub to custom Rest end point

Tags: rest, azure-iot-hub

I have used Raspberry Pi to send some IOT data to the Azure IOT Hub.
Also, I have created Ubuntu VM on Azure and configured a custom rest end point to hit my service code. Now I want to send the data from IOT hub to the custom rest endpoint. I know that Azure by default has end points like Azure Storage containers, Service Bus, but I want to send data to the custom rest end point.

Can someone let me know how to do it!!

Thanks!

Comment: As it stands, this question is too broad. Consider posting what you're tried thus far and we can help you from there...

Comment: Hey War10ck,

I have used Raspberry Pi to send some IOT data to the Azure IOT Hub. Also, I have created an Ubuntu VM on Azure and configured a custom rest end point to hit my service code.

Now I want to send the IOT data from IOT hub to the custom rest endpoint.
I know that Azure by default has end points like Azure Storage containers, Service Bus, but I want to send data to the custom rest end point.

Thanks!

Comment: @karthiknujella You can update your question by adding this detailed information instead of in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

> IoT Hub currently supports the following Azure services as additional
>   endpoints:
>
> - Azure Storage containers
> - Event Hubs
> - Service Bus Queues
> - Service Bus Topics

Reference "[Custom endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-endpoints#custom-endpoints)".

For your use case, maybe you can add an [Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview) between IoT Hub and your custom REST endpoint for routing messages. Azure Functions can be triggered by IoT Hub when the message arrived in. Then you can send REST request to your REST endpoint in Function.

Reference "[Processing data from IoT Hub with Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/functions-js-iot-hub-processing/)"